# how to fix the following error : undefined method `PUT' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing:: Mapper:0x3f8ee48> in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am currently trying to create a shopping cart for my rails application and once populated my cart should be saved in the session.

Everytime i try to run the server to test if working or not, it seems my routes are not working at all...

See below my routes.rb, my cart controller and my index.

Any help will be appreciated.

routes.rb

```
    Sewingsupplies::Application.routes.draw do
  get "cart/index"

  get "cart/success"

  PUT "/cart/:id" => "cart#add"
  DELETE "/cart/:id" => "cart#remove"
  DELETE "/cart" => "cart#clear"
  POST "/cart/checkout"

  devise_for :admins

  resources :catalogues


  devise_for :users
```

cart controller

```
      def index
        sessions[:cart] = {}
        render 'cart/index'
      end

      def success
      end


      def add

        @catalogue = Catalogue.find(params[:id])
        cart = sessions[:cart]
        cart = {:catalogue => @catalogue.name,category => @catalogue.category, :code => @catalogue.code , :colour=> @catalogue.colour, :description => @catalogue.description, :image  => @catalogue.image , :unitprice => += @catalogue.unitprice, :unitquantity => +=1, :unitweight => += @catalogue.unitweight }
        sessions[:cart] = cart
        render 'cart/add'
      end
end
```

and my index page

```
<h1>Listing catalogues</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Unitprice</th>
    <th>Unitquantity</th>
    <th>Unitweight</th>
    <th>Colour</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @catalogues.each do |catalogue| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= catalogue.name %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.code %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.category %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.description %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.unitprice %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.unitquantity %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.unitweight %></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.colour %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag(catalogue.image, :width => 150) if catalogue.image.present?%></td>
    <td><%= catalogue.user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', catalogue %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_catalogue_path(catalogue) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', catalogue, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Add to cart", controller: "cart", action: "add", id: @catalogue.id, method: :post %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<%= link_to "View cart", controller: "cart", action: "index" %>

<%= link_to 'New Catalogue', new_catalogue_path %>
```

Comment: Use smallcase put and delete methods in routes.rb instead of PUT and DELETE

Comment: Well, it worked... Can run server now... i would have thought it would have not make a difference to have lower or upper put and delete

Comment: Check my answer, why it should be lower case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes.rb file you have defined the routes with PUT and DELETE in uppercase. Define the routes in lowercase like **put and delete** as these are methods of **ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper** class which are called to setup routes for your application. As ruby is case sensitive you need to call the method with correct case.